# How to prevent no sql injetion when using Morphia with java ee?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, owasp, nosql-injection

I'm using MongoDB with Morphia Object Document Mapper in Java EE.

```
@Override
public void removeTrustedDevice(String username, String cookieValue) {
    MongoConnection conn = MongoConnection.getInstance();
    TrustedDeviceDao dao = new TrustedDeviceDao(conn.getDatastore());
    Query<TrustedDevice> query = dao.createQuery();
    query.and(
            query.criteria("username").equal(username),
            query.criteria("cookieValue").equal(cookieValue)
    );

    List<TrustedDevice> deviceList = query.asList();

    if (deviceList != null && !deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        dao.delete(deviceList.get(0));
    }
}
```

Is there any probability for No SQL injection? If yes, so please give me suggestion or example for prevention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't say that the chances of such an attack are *0* because hackers are clever, determined types but I will say that you needn't worry overly much about it and that, in all my years of working with and for MongoDB, I've never heard of such an attack being carried out.

SQL injection attacks work, in part, by leveraging the fact that SQL queries are parsed and evaluated on the server side.  Mongo queries arrive at the server already in `Document` format.  MongoDB queries don't support comments in the same way as SQL does and so that attack vector isn't available.  Because the queries are already in a well-defined, structured format and aren't parsed on the server, it is much, much harder to pull off a similar attack.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you give me the example of best practice? (vulnerable and secure code using **Morphia**). [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet_in_Java)

Comment: Hey @evanchooly, please help me to make vulnerable free application.

Comment: First of all @vijay Kumar, you need to validate `username` and `cookieValue`